# how to copy java file from one pacakge to another dynamically changing package name

Tags: java

i need to copy the file content from one package to another but when i copy the content package file name is same i need to copy by dynamically changing package name according to the destination package can any on please help me to solve this problem

code is something like
src: pakage is asm

```
pakage asm;
public class lpl{
.... body
}
```

dest:
package is lohith

when i copy output will be like

```
pakage asm;
public class lpl{
.... body
}
```

i want something like this

```
pakage lohith;
public class lpl{
.... body
}
```

Comment: Use IDE likes Eclipse. https://www.eclipse.org/downloads

Comment: do you want to java code for coping file ?

Comment: Use an AST parser [like this one](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/AST.html) or operate on the compiled bytecode using an API [like this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ObjectWeb_ASM).

Answer (score 0):

What IDE are you using (Eclipse, IntelliJ, NetBeans, other) ?

If you're not using one, you should, it would make your life easier.

If you are using an IDE (out of the list above), they should all have a "Refactoring" menu, with a "Move" refactoring option. Use that one to move the class to the new package.

If you cannot use an IDE, you need to do the refactoring by hand, which is tricky:

1. Find all usages of the class in imports (using grep of some other search) and keep a note of them somewhere
2. Move the actual class to the new location
3. Change the package declaration of the class to the new package (it must match the directory !)
4. Go over all the imports from the list you kept in stage 1, and change them to the new package

**A word of caution:** When you move classes around packages, you might inadvertently have moved them out of a packaged JAR file if using a build system of some kind (Ant, Maven, Gradle, etc.). Make sure that your move of the file does not break module dependencies, and if it does, make sure to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse or any IDE you are using, you can drag the class and drop it into the new package and it will change the package statement for you for the new/copy class